# Can I assign a parent category in navigation to not link to anything?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

Weird question that probably needs a person that know magento very weal to answer. I am new to magento and I created a mega menu with categories that will link to cms pages I made. The main category labeled "about us" links to a default category page. We actually don't want this page to link to anything. We just want to use it for the mega menu drop down. Does any one know how to fix this? I can make a url rewrite if it was going to a cms page but I dont want it to link to anything?

Thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it to link to anything just do a url rewrite and send it to #
This will make it open the same page from where it is open.
Like http://www.example.com/#